# Deploy Webpack on Nginx Subpath

Tags: node.js, nginx, webpack, webpack-2

## Explanation of my Doubt

I got an app running and holded on a Docker Container usign:

- Webpack
- React Router 4
- Express.js
- GraphQL

My app works perfect under a Root Folder `www.mycoolurl.com/`. But i got other app running on my root so i created `www.mycoolrul.com/coolsubpath`

#### Express

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist"));

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
});
```

#### Nginx Config

```
upstream coolapp{
    server       1.1.1.1:8000;
}



location /coolsubpath {
    # Upstream
    proxy_pass         http://coolapp/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    client_max_body_size 3M;
}
```

My first experience with this was awful ... every request tried to mount my App, Vendor and Manifest (webpack stuff, that only need to be mounted on root). So i end up doing this:

#### Webpack Config

```
output: {
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    chunkFilename: "[chunkhash].js",
    publicPath: "/"
},
```

Now only the root will load the assets but... when i go to `www.mycoolrul.com/coolsubpath` only my index.html is found and ...[image: Assets Loading]

The assets are looking for my ex. `www.mycoolurl.com/app.761c16f76fcba6601577.js/` instead of `www.mycoolrul.com/coolsubpath/app.761c16f76fcba6601577.js/`.

## What i Expect

I tested adding `React Router 4` subpath... and my `Express.js` the subpath name to the `.get` and `.use` methods. Yes, it works. But now i want my subpath to be instead of `coolsubpath` like ex. `mynewsupercoolsubpath`. I have to rebuild and deploy the app again ?.

## What i tried...

I tried rewriting the `request url` but had no luck, i know the code is wrong... but i dont know how to do it

```
if ($http_referer ~* ^www.mycoolrul.com/coolsubpath ) {
   set $request_url /coolsubpath/$1;
}
```

Comment: My temporal solution is to add the `/subpath` to all my stuff... like RR4... Express... Webpack... maybe this is the way ? it doesnt feel good.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify `publicPath` setting in your webpack configuration - https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/
and rebuild your scripts. This way your index.html file will reference scripts and other resources with the appropriate subpath.

If you use express only to serve static, then nginx can do that for you. Watch out how your dist folder is served, you might want to place it in a /subpath exactly as it is served, but that depends on proxy settings, wether it rewrites path or not.